# Wordpress header does not support characters

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress header , it replaces some characters with  which means it does not support set characters. But others parts of the site display those characters normally. I added  to the header but it still does not display characters as it should , how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

have a meta tag in your header that sets the charset to one that supports all the characters you're trying to use, UTF-8 should work fine. Like so: `<meta content="charset=utf-8">` I mean, you should definantely have more that that in your meta, but this is the para that would fin your problem. If this doesn't fix it, switch the 8 to a 16. You can continue to 32 or even 64 for some extremely obscure characters if necessary.

Comment: i added this header but still , the characters arent displayed properly

Comment: What specific characters aren't showing up? Also, I mas have been wrong, try taking out the content part and going with <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: tried it , still doesnt work , the characeters are  ž,ý,á,ú

Comment: Sorry, use UTF-16 not 8